# Google Chrome Calling Express API -- Access to fetch at from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, fetch-api

I have an API written in Express/nodeJS that is hosted in GCloud.  The cors middle wear is enabled and responding to 'OPTIONS' request.  When I attempt to call the API on a local server I can access the API.  When I attempt to access the api once deployed I get the following error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://___.com/player' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I am able to see the call to 'OPTIONS' in Chrome and it is returning the following headers:

```
access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
alt-svc: clear
content-length: 0
date: Tue, 05 May 2020 18:40:13 GMT
status: 204
vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
via: 1.1 google
x-powered-by: Express
```

My request looks like this:

```
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
authorization: Bearer cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 31
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
origin: http://localhost:3000
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sessionid: 
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
```

My fetch call from React is:

```
        const response = await fetch(
            'https://___.com/player',

            {
                method: 'patch',
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: new Headers({
                    authorization: 'Bearer ' + appState.User.token,
                    sessionId: `${appState.SessionId}`,
                }),
                body: patch,
            }
        );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a full day of testing and we finally figured this out.  It was not a CORS error at all, Chrome was reporting it as such which was causing confusion.  Also, this was working when running through Fiddler.

Turns out that the methods in fetch are case sensitive.  changing patch to PATCH resolved the issue.